# Bootstrap Accordion with dynamic ajax content

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I want to create an accordion with a content from ajax.

So, my HTML is :

```
<div class="latestinfo panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
// DYNAMIC CONTENT HERE
</div>
```

and my success ajax is :

```
success: function(data) {
            data.items.forEach(function(e) {
                $('.latestinfo').append('<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne"><h4 class="panel-title"><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">' + e.title + '</a></h4></div><div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne"><div class="panel-body">' + e.content + '</div></div></div>');
            });
       }
```

Currently ,

- The content is displayed
- When i click the first one it open
- When i click  other, the first toggle ( open / close )

The problem is that the accordion is not working correctly as I described above.

Comment: Just remove a class `.in`, which makes  accordion open, from `.panel-collapse`. Plus, from what I see, there is a problem with duplicated id for all accordions. All of them have the same `#headingOne` id. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: @kwiat1990 Thank you !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `id` **MUST BE UNIQUE** (say it loud and imagine echo)...

You can use the `index` provided by `.forEach()` to create unique `id`.
;)

And you can use `+` to concatenate a string on multiple lines...
Improves readability.

```js
// Assuming this JSON.
var data = {items:[{title:"ONE",content:"Something-1"},
                   {title:"TWO",content:"Something-2"},
                   {title:"THREE",content:"Something-3"}
                  ]
           };


var success = function(data) {
  data.items.forEach(function(item,index) {
    $('.latestinfo').append(
        '<div class="panel panel-default">'+
          '<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading_'+index+'">'+
            '<h4 class="panel-title">'+
              '<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse_'+index+'" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse_'+index+'">'+
                  item.title+
              '</a>'+
            '</h4>'+
          '</div>'+
          '<div id="collapse_'+index+'" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading_'+index+'">'+
            '<div class="panel-body">'+
              item.content+
            '</div>'+
          '</div>'+
        '</div>'
      );
  });
}

// Feaking an ajax response...
success(data);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="latestinfo panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
// DYNAMIC CONTENT HERE
</div>
```

Comment: Could this be used to do the same thing with each row having not a header but four table cells contained within it?

Comment: Sure... You can append the structure you want. Here, it's a Bootstrap accordion, but it can be whatever.