# Accordion List Using Jquery and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm Trying to Implement an accordion list. So basically this a bootstrap accordion. The title of the accordion is already set by PHP. When the user clicks the accordion it must display list of the session that is coming from server. I am using an ajax call for this, the issue every time I click the accordion only first elements get the results. Other elements didn't get the result just a blank view is displayed. I am fairly new to jquery. Here is my Html Code

```
<div class="accordion" id="myAccordion">
    <?php foreach($modules as $module): ?>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button id="<?php echo $module->id;?>" type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#collapse<?php echo $module->id; ?>"><?php echo $module->module_name; ?></button>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse<?php echo $module->id; ?>" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
            data-parent="#myAccordion">
            <div class="card-body">
                <ul id="sessionlist" class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <i class="icon-play_circle_outline text-blue"></i><a href="#">'+data[i].session_name+'</a>' +
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

This is my Jquery and ajax code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>dashboard/displaysession/" + this.id,
                type: 'GET',
                data: {},
                error: function () {
                    alert('Something is wrong');
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var myhtmlstring = '<li class="list-group-item">' +
                            '<i class="icon-play_circle_outline text-blue"></i><a href="#">' +
                            data[i].session_name + '</a>' +
                            '</li>';
                        console.log($.parseHTML(myhtmlstring));
                        $("#sessionlist").append($.parseHTML(myhtmlstring));
                    }
                },
                dataType: 'json'
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Really appricate your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap Accordion with dynamic ajax content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377394/bootstrap-accordion-with-dynamic-ajax-content)

Comment: already seen doesn't work in my case

Comment: i am trying to load the data on button click not trying to load the whole accordion

Comment: Okay then please add your static code to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so that we can easily find problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give your sessionlists unique ids aswell. Because when you append your myhtmlstring to #sessionlist it only ever takes the first one.

```
<ul id="sessionlist<?php echo $module->id; ?>" class="list-group list-group-flush">
   <li class="list-group-item">
     <i class="icon-play_circle_outline text-blue"></i><a href="#">'+data[i].session_name+'</a>' +
   </li>
</ul>
```

then you can append it to the right sessionlist in your ajax success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            const currentModuleId = this.id
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>dashboard/displaysession/" + currentModuleId ,
                type: 'GET',
                data: {},
                error: function () {
                    alert('Something is wrong');
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#sessionlist" + currentModuleId ).html("");
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var myhtmlstring = '<li class="list-group-item">' +
                            '<i class="icon-play_circle_outline text-blue"></i><a href="#">' +
                            data[i].session_name + '</a>' +
                            '</li>';
                        console.log($.parseHTML(myhtmlstring));
                        $("#sessionlist" + currentModuleId ).append($.parseHTML(myhtmlstring));
                    }
                },
                dataType: 'json'
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: It is working but adding the duplicate list item to my code. How can I remove ?

Comment: you could use $("#sessionlist" + currentModuleId ).html($.parseHTML(myhtmlstring)); instead of append. Then you reset the inner HTML instead of appending to it

Comment: using .html() will only add the last element of loop. instead, I have used $("button").one('click',function (){});

Comment: or you could leave it and just clear it before the for loop starts. see my updated answer @RohitJain